# eloquent sort according to newly created attribute

Tags: php, laravel, sorting, eloquent

I am using Laravel 4.2(I know its old) for my project. I will try my best to explain my problem.

My aim is to access all the records(from database) for each user. Calculate the sum of their transaction and sort in descending order.

What I have done is:
I have a controller where I access user's ID and call to Repositories method `getAllTransactions` to get all the transaction of user.

```
$entries = \Repositories\Something::getUsers();

foreach ($entries as $key => $entry) {
    //calculate total transaction
    $userTransactions        = \Repositories\Something::getAllTransactions($entry->user_id);
    $entry->totalTransaction = $userTransactions;
}
```

Then in my `Repositories`, I called `SomeModel` and get all transactions. Then, I looped and add transaction amount and return to controller.

```
$userTransaction = \SomeModel::where('status', '1')
                               ->where('user_id', $user_id)
                               ->get();

$totalTransactionAmount = 0;

foreach($userTransaction as $transaction) {
    $totalTransactionAmount = $totalTransactionAmount + $transaction->amount;
}

return $totalTransactionAmount;
```

And finally, I assign the return value to `$entries` object making new attribute totalTransaction like:

```
$entry->totalTransaction = $userTransactions;
```

as shown in first code sample.
Now, I want to sort the `$entries` according to newly created attribute `totalTransaction` in descending order. Is it possible to sort eloquent object `$entries` by newly added attribute? If yes, how can I complete it?
Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank You!